# How can I get output of sentencepiece function as array format?

Tags: vectorization, machine-translation

I am converting word to vector where I need to get vector as type array int format but I am getting array object type.

Can anyone help me with solution?

```
def word2idx(statement):
        #here I am using sentencepieceprocessor as sp
        id1 = np.asarray(sp.encode_as_ids(statement)).astype(np.int32)
        return id1

sentence = 'the world', 'hello cherry', 'make me proud'
id2 = [word2idx(s)for s in sentence]
print(id2)
```

actual output:

```
[[array([  34, 1867]), array([ 83, 184,  63,  50,  47,  71,  41]), array([328,  69,   7, 303, 649])]]
```

Expect output:

```
[[ 34, 1867], [ 83, 184,  63,  50,  47,  71,  41], [328,  69,   7, 303, 649]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrays are of different lengths, so numpy cannot make tensor out of it.

If you are happy with a **list of lists** and don't need a numpy array, you can do:

```py
id2 = np.array([[  34, 1867], [ 83, 184,  63,  50,  47,  71,  41]])
id2.tolist()
```

and get: `[[34, 1867], [83, 184, 63, 50, 47, 71, 41]]`.

You need a **dense numpy array**, you need to pad all sequence to the same length. You can do something like:

```py
id2 = np.array([[  34, 1867], [ 83, 184,  63,  50,  47,  71,  41]])
idx = np.zeros((len(id2), max(len(s) for s in id2)))
for i, sent_ids in enumerate(id2):
    idx[i,:len(sent_ids)] = sent_ids
```

In this case you will get:

```
array([[  34., 1867.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [  83.,  184.,   63.,   50.,   47.,   71.,   41.]])
```

Comment: Cool, if you the answer solves your issue, please mark it as a correct one, so the others know.